# WPF, updating status bar in main window from within UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, event-handling, statusbar

I have a `StatusBar` in my main window, and I also have a copy of a `UserControl` in my main window.  From within event handlers in my `UserControl`, I want to update the `StatusBar` in the main window.  What would be the best way of doing this?  Is there a way of getting access to the instance of my main window from `object sender` or `RoutedEventArgs e` in an event handler in `UserControl`?

**Edit:**  thanks to [lukas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460531/wpf-updating-status-bar-in-main-window-from-within-usercontrol/3460784#3460784) and [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers), I came up with the following solution:

Added to my `UserControl`:

```
public delegate void UpdateStatusBarEventHandler(string message);

public event UpdateStatusBarEventHandler UpdateStatusBar;
```

Added to my main window's constructor, after `InitializeComponent`:

```
uct_requiredFields.UpdateStatusBar += updateStatusBar;
```

And I added this method to my main window:

```
private void updateStatusBar(string message)
{
    sti_mainStatus.Content = message;
}
```

Then, from within my `UserControl`, I can do the following to update the status bar:

```
if (null != UpdateStatusBar)
{
    UpdateStatusBar("woot, message");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add an event to UserControl via my own delegate or defined

```
public event UpdateStatusBar UpdateBar;
```

and then rise it via button click in UserControl ( or other thing that u use)

```
    private void UserContolButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(UpdateBar != null)
          UpdateBar(); // send here the message
    }
```

I assume u have an instance of UserControl in the main window
in contructor

```
 myUserControl.UpdateBar += MyMethodWhichUpdatesStatusBar();
```